# AWS: Find the endpoint of my DB Instance using the cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I want to find the endpoint of my DB Instance using the command-line interface, but I got this error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-lopes:/ lopes$ aws rds describe-db-instances  

A client error (InvalidClientTokenId) occurred when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I tried to check my credentials, but I got also an error

```
MacBook-Pro-de-lopes:/ lopes$ cd ~/.aws/credentials
-bash: cd: /Users/lopes/.aws/credentials: Not a directory
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using the console"? Your question is showing the AWS CLI, not the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have invalid credentials configured for you [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

You can view the configuration via:

```
cat ~/.aws/credentials
```

Or, you can view/configure them via:

```
aws configure
```

See: [Configuring the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)